# how to get the size of a \pgfdeclareimage

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, dimensions

Basically I want to use a TikZ node to frame a pgfimage, so later on, I will add more and connect them as I see fit.
I have this:

```
\pgfdeclareimage[width=10em]{image1}{images/image1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (MM) [rectangle,draw,thick,minimum width=10.15em,label=below:Description]{\pgfbox[center,center]{\pgfuseimage{image1}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So now I need to get the height of image1 to add minimum height property in the node declaration. This way I can get a dynamic framing independent of the aspect ratio of the image. Maybe it's an easy task but I'm newbie to this and can't seem to find the information I need in the documentation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Why don’t you set greater `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` values instead of using `minimum width` and `minimum height`?

Comment: thanks for the reply, but with that I have the same problem. I don't know to which value I should set the `inner ysep`, since depending on the aspect ratio, it will vary (I'm only fixing width=10em), I could manually adjust it but in the future I want to put more images in an automated way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\pgfdeclareimage` does not use or measure the image, but you can get the height by using LaTeX's `\settoheight`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength\imageheight

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=10em]{image1}{images/image1}
\settoheight{\imageheight}{\pgfuseimage{image1}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (MM) [
    rectangle,
    draw,
    thick,
    minimum width=10.15em,
    minimum height=\the\dimexpr\imageheight+.15em\relax,
    label=below:Description
  ]{\pgfbox[center,center]{\pgfuseimage{image1}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```